# action won't run on a CCSprite from within ccTouchBegan in cocos2d for iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, touch

I'm trying to basically scale up a button as soon as a touch is detected. Here's my Scene:

```
@implementation HomeScene

-(id) init
{
  if((self = [super init])) {
    ...
    // sp_btn_story is retained...
    sp_btn_story = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"main_menu_btn.png"] retain];
    sp_btn_story.position = ccp(size.width - 146, 110);
    [self addChild: sp_btn_story];
    ...
  }
  return self;
}

-(void) onEnter
{
  [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:0 swallowsTouches:YES];
}

-(void) onExit
{
  [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
}

- (BOOL)ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
  NSLog(@"tapped!");
  sp_btn_story.scaleX = 2;

  [sp_btn_story stopAllActions];
  [sp_btn_story runAction: [CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.5f scale:1.2f]];
  return YES;
}

...

@end
```

It scales the X just fine, as expected. (I threw that in there to test.) But the action is not running for some reason. :( Anyone have any ideas?

Edit: using cocos2d 0.99 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this question (reposted from the asker's own comment to make it more visible):

> It's quite important to call

```
[super onEnter];
```

> if you overwrite this method in a subclass or strange things may happen. Cocos2D will not be happy.
>
> This applies to other (if not all) methods as well, e. g. always call

```
[super onExit];
```

> as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not complete sure what could be going on.  Looks like what you have should work fine but you may want to try applying a different action to `sp_btn_story` like fade in or fade out to see if at least any action will work.  Failing that you could also try applying the action in a different part of your code.  These are not solutions but they may provide evidence to indicate what exactly is going on.

Comment: Rob: thanks a bunch for the suggestions. I had a hunch that it was because I was adding the sprite in "init" and not "onEnter," but I finally narrowed it down to the exact cause. It was the because I didn't have [super onEnter]; Oops. I added that and it animated just fine. Good to know!

Comment: No problem.  I made that exact same mistake some weeks ago.  Forgetting to call [super onEnter] seriously messes with Cocos2D.  Don't forget to call [super onExit] as well!!

Comment: Nice, I came across the same problem, thanks for pointing out that a missing [super onEnter] was the cause of the problem. I added this as an answer, to make the solution more clear.